# Change an img (last/first child) in a div on hover

Tags: css

I have a couple of Div's on my page and I'd like to change the colour and img when a mouse is hovering over them.

So I changing the text colour from grey to blue would be very easy.

```
CSS
#div1:hover{color:#0000CC}
```

And changing an img is done by

```
CSS
a img:last-child {
  display: none;  
}

a:hover {
    Color: var(--Ability-orange);
}

a:hover img:last-child {    
  display: block;  
}

a:hover img:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Both easy to do..

However if I have a div with text and two imgs inside dragging the mouse over the div only changes the text (dragging mouse over img as its in the div changes both).

Any ideas ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Vision</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      padding: 25px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      height: 90%;
    }
    
    #div1:hover {
      Color: #0066CC;
    }
    
    a img:last-child {
      display: none;
    }
    
    a:hover img:last-child {
      display: block;
    }
    
    a:hover img:first-child {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- page container-->

    <div id="div1" style="font-size:x-large">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="2%">
            <a><img src="../Images/on.png" width="32" height="32" /> <img src="../Images/off.png" width="32" height="32" /></a>
          </td>
          <td width="98%">Change this text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- page container-->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html also?

Comment: edited -sorry about that...

Comment: Do you want to change `change this text` when hovering `a`?

Comment: Can you please explain it more. not getting clear idea

Comment: Yes **kmgt** images and text          **mohitesachin** I have a div that has text and images (childs; first and last) when a mouse pointer is hovering OVER the div i want the text and the img to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the images to change when you hover over the div, so change the `a:hover (etc.)` rules to `#div1:hover a (etc.)`

```css
.container {
    padding:25px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height: 90%;    
}

#div1{
    min-height: 90px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#div1 img{
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#div1:hover{
    Color:#0066CC;  
}

a img:last-child {
  display: none;  
}

#div1:hover a img:last-child {    
  display: block;  
}

#div1:hover a img:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  <!-- page container-->
  <div id="div1" style="font-size:x-large">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
              <td width="2%">
                  <a>
                      <img src="http://placekitten.com/190/190" width="80" height="80" /> 
                      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="80" height="80" />
                  </a>
              </td>
              <td width="98%">Change this text</td>
          </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent !! Thank you symlink, its been doing my head in for a few hours.